# React native useEffect cleanUp function errors

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

When I use `useEffect` sometimes I faced an error called `useEffect` cleanup function. and I cant find a solution. it doesn't prevent my app from running here are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You did not write a cleanup function.
Read [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/m18tzg/can_set_state_inside_useeffect_cleanup_function/)

Example from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function FriendStatus(props) {
    const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleStatusChange(status) {
            setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
        }
        ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
        // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
        return function cleanup() {
            ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
        };
    });

    if (isOnline === null) {
        return 'Loading...';
    }
    return isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```